# Why local variable within inline function expanded multiple times in "discrete statements" can have a single set of variables?

Tags: c++

I'm reading *Inside The C++ Object Model* and find confused about inline function expansion.

> > In general, each local variable within the inline function must be introduced into the enclosing block of the call
> >     as a uniquely named variable. If the inline function is expanded multiple times within one expression, each
> >     expansion is likely to require its own set of the local variables. If the inline function is expanded multiple
> >     times in **discrete statements**, however, a single set of the local variables can probably be reused across the
> >     multiple expansions.

Here, what does it mean to expand inline function multiple times in **discrete statements** and how could that happen? Can anyone raise a concrete example to apply this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble to handle the term **discrete statement** (especially because it has been emphasized multiple times). I tried to find something like a clear definition (by google) but I couldn't. Thus, I decided to read this literally as *one statement* (with *discrete* in the sense of *separate*).

Denoting a function `inline` is just a hint to the compiler that the programmer would like to have the function body inserted directly at every "call point" (instead of simply calling the function). Actually, the compiler decides whether the function is really inlined. (It might be even inlined at one point of call but become a function call at another point.) If a macro is used instead of the inline function, the inline requirement would be granted (as macro expansion is actually nothing else than text replacement). Of course, macros have a lot of limitations which inline functions have not. One of them is that inline functions may have local variables.

I made a synthetic example. It's not code "ready for production" but it hopefully helps to illustrate the topic:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline int absValue(int a)
{
  int mB = -a;
  return a < 0 ? mB : a;
}

int main()
{
  int value;
  // use input to prevent compile-time computation
  cout << "input: " << flush;
  cin >> value;
  // multiple usages of absValue()
  cout << "value: " << value << endl
    << "absValue(value): "
    << absValue(value)
    << endl
    << "absValue(-value): "
    << absValue(-value)
    << endl;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

The second output statement calls function `absValue()` multiple times where the call should be inlined. I imagine it like:

```
  // multiple usages of absValue()
  cout << "value: " << value << endl
    << "absValue(value): "
    << {
         int mB = -(value);
         return (value) < 0 ? mB : (value);
       }
    << endl
    << "absValue(-value): "
    << {
         int mB = -(-value);
         return (-value) < 0 ? mB : (-value);
       }
    << endl;
```

There are two occurrences of `mB` in this statement. On one hand, these are two separate local variables. On the other hand, they may share the same storage on stack as they are used consecutively. (They might not share the same storage if the compiler optimization introduces some kind of code re-ordering which results in interleaving of the first and second expansion of `absValue()`.)

This whole explanation is rather theoretically. Practically, the compiler will hopefully put `mB` into a register or even optimize most of the code away.

I fiddled a little bit with [**godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/g/8rK8JF) to illustrate it further. Finally, I must admit that it proofs essentially my last paragraph above.